# Как настроить роуты в Django + React?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, api, django-rest-framework

**У меня не получается правильно настроить роуты**

**Конкретнее:** 
Сейчас работает так, что по пути есть ***localhost:8000/api/*** передается api в json формате,
а по пути ***localhost:3000/*** - фронтенд на реакте, так всё работает правильно

**НО**

Я хочу сделать так, чтоб api работал по пути ***localhost:8000/api/todos/***, а фронт на ***localhost:3000/todos/***, но у меня не получается сделать никак вообще, я не понимаю

**Возможно это делается всё очень просто, подскажите, пожалуйста!**

Вот мой код:

***config*** - папка с настройками, главная папка django

***todos*** - приложение

***frontend*** - папка с реактом

**config/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path # new

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('todos.urls')), # new
]
```

**todos/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ListTodo, DetailTodo

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailTodo.as_view()),
    path('', ListTodo.as_view()),
]
```

**todos/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**todos/views.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Todo
from .serializers import TodoSerializer

class ListTodo(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

class DetailTodo(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
```

**todos/serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Todo

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'body',)
```

**fronteds/src/App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 

class App extends Component {
    state = {
      todos: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getTodos();
    }

    getTodos() {
      axios
        .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({todos: res.data });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div> 
              {this.state.todos.map(item => ( 
                  <div key = {item.id}>
                      <h1>{item.title}</h1> 
                      <span>{item.body}</span>
                  </div>
              ))} 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: через nginx делай

Comment: @alex, хорошо, я посмотрю. Если без этого, то не вариант вообще? Может можно как-то?

Comment: У меня получилось сделать так:
Путь для api на localhost:8000/api/todos/.
Следовательно в App.js меняем на .get('127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos').
С этим всё хорошо, реакт его видит.
Теперь нужно сделать так, чтоб реакт работал не по localhost:3000/, а по localhost:3000/todos/.
Было бы логично сменить в todos/urls.py путь на path('todos/', ListTodo.as_view())
В таком случае реакт просто не работает, ни по тому пути, ни по другому.
Наверное это не работает потому что я меняю роуты для django всё-таки.
Как изменить путь для реакта по другому я не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось исправить, решил так:
Путь до api сменил на ***localhost:8000/api/todos/***

В App.js изменил путь до api так:         `.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/')`

В index.js добавил роуты:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const Routing = () => {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="todos/"  element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Routing />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```